# How to return a List of all values in a field

Tags: c#, search, solr, solrnet

I have a document like:

```
{
"Id":"1",
"Name":"product1",      
"Categories":["Cat1",
  "Cat2",
  "Cat3"]
},
{
"Id":"2",
"Name":"product2",      
"Categories":["Cat3",
  "Cat2",
  "Cat6"]
}
```

Now I want return a distinct List of all categories.
I tried CollapseParameter, but it doesn't work.

```
var foo = _solr.Query(new SolrQuery("*"), new QueryOptions
{
    Collapse = new CollapseParameters("Categories")
});

var bar= results.CollapseExpand; //NULL
```

How can I get a list of all categories without iterating through all the documents? Do I have to create new Documents for the categories? Or should I work with Faceting?

Comment: Faceting will give you all categories and a count for each, i.e. `"Cat3": "2"`, etc. If that's what you want, then faceting is what you're looking for.

Comment: I want a list of all categories. So the customer can use the categories as a filter for later search requests. There will be a gui with checkboxes for all the categories.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can do it using LINQ.

Comment: Sure I can get all Documents and use LINQ. But I think that would be a performance problem. Why should I get all the documents, if I only need the categories? I could only get the category field from solr, but it's still the same problem (get all the documents and us LINQ)
Also there isn't a SQL DB with all the categories in it.

Comment: That's a facet, so add a facet field for `Categories` and you'll get a list of all categories matching the current query and their associated counts back.

Comment: I know and I will use the facets in the later queries. I want the facet before I create the first query. Currently I'm working with a query to return 1 Recipe and all the category facets. I hope there would be a better way.

Comment: You're going to have to issue a query, since the facets is a result of a query. If you don't want to search for anything specific, use a query of `*:*` and `rows` set to `0`. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. I post my solution, but I'm not happy with it. I search for nothing, just to get all the categories.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON is not valid. So I created a solution changing the Json:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "product1",
        "Categories": ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"]
    }, {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "product2",
        "Categories": ["Cat3", "Cat2", "Cat6"]
    }]
}
```

And then, I used foreach and LINQ structure:

```
var x = categories.SelectMany(item => item.Categories).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using solr and you want all distinct value for specific field then must start reading solr faceting doc, its amazing.

Only add below query in your query and you we get full list of all distinct categories.

```
&facet=true&facet.field=Categories
```

> That's it, It will gives result set as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions
{
    StartOrCursor = new StartOrCursor.Start(0),
    Rows = 1,
    Facet = new FacetParameters { Queries = new[] { new SolrFacetFieldQuery("Categories") } }
};

var result = _solrConnection.Query(new SolrQuery("*"), options);

if (result.FacetFields.ContainsKey("Categories"))
{
    return result.FacetFields["Categories"]
        .Where(li => li.Value > 0)
        .Select(y=> y.Key)
        .ToList();
}
```

That's my current solution. It works, but I hoped there would be a better way. I'm searching for a result just to get all the categories.